# List of available cameras and drivers in ROS

Tags: ros, camera1394, camera-drivers, uvc-camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

I am preparing a tutorial on image processing in ROS and would thus like to present a list of currently available cameras and associated drivers in ROS. I am aware of the camera_drivers stack (http://www.ros.org/wiki/camera_drivers) which supports some of the FireWire and GE cameras. Recently there has been an initiative to plug in a driver for usb cameras which will mostly likely be based off the uvc_camers driver (http://www.ros.org/wiki/uvc_camera). The discussion on the latter is available here: http://ros-users.122217.n3.nabble.com/call-for-an-official-ROS-USB-camera-package-td2116581.html.
Additionally we also have a driver for Kinect (http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni_camera) and SR (http://www.ros.org/wiki/swissranger_camera).
Does anyone have more information and maybe a list of cameras that work with the above mentioned drivers?
Many thx in advance, D.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10619/list-of-available-cameras-and-drivers--in-ros/) by [dejanpan](https://answers.ros.org/users/92/dejanpan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1420 on 2011-07-17

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This page lists sensor support in ROS:

http://www.ros.org/wiki/Sensors

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-07-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dejanpan](https://answers.ros.org/users/92/dejanpan/) on 2011-07-17**:
ahh, great, thx